# Replacing a character within a print function without using .replace

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace, character

I am new to programming and have a question about replacing text within a print function in Python.

In my current code, for a count down, if you enter 5 it will print "5431GO", how could I get it to replace the previous character? I have done it before but I forgot how, I think it was something to do with "\r"?

```
import time

countdown_time = int(input("Enter amount of seconds to count down from: "))
while countdown_time >= 0:
    if countdown_time == 0:
        print("GO")
        break
    else:
        print(countdown_time, end="")
        countdown_time -= 1
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Yes, `\r` is carriage return. It goes to the beginning of the line without going to the next line.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly like you stated, `\r` means it will move the pointer to the start of the line, just use it in your `print` statement like this:

```py
import time

countdown_time = int(input("Enter amount of seconds to count down from: "))
while countdown_time >= 0:
    if countdown_time == 0:
        print("GO")
        break
    else:
        print(countdown_time, end="\r")
        countdown_time -= 1
        time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: Thanks that what I thought but when I do this, no text is getting printed until the times over and then it prints go, do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @KevinNisbet mmm, don't know what's the problem, maybe try running it without an IDE. They sometimes mess up with the terminal.

Comment: Might want to have the print statement be ```print(f"{countdown_time}......", end="\r")``` so that previous numbers get completely overwritten, otherwise the count goes from 10 to 90. ```print(str(countdown_time) + "......", end="\r")``` would also work.

Comment: Ah yeah, I ran it with notepad and it kind of worked, my new problem is now if the input is "10", it replaces the "9" with the "10" 's "1" and I get "90"  :(

Comment: Thanks @neutrino_logic got rid of that problem now too :D Thanks guys!

Comment: @KevinNisbet, if it solved your problem, consider selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to update a percentage text inline. Just call the `update_percentage` instead of `print`.

```
def update_percentage(row_string):
    row_string = str(row_string)

    # clear previous text
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write(" " * len(row_string))

    # reposition at the start of the row
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write(row_string)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```